# Create codeigniter navigation on single post

Tags: php, codeigniter, pagination, codeigniter-3

My goal is creating prev/next navigation in codeigniter single post based on article ID. I'm using CI built-in library and it produces pagination links like this:

```
<a data-ci-pagination-page="1" href=(some url)>Page 1</a>
<a data-ci-pagination-page="2" href=(some url)>Page 2</a>
<a data-ci-pagination-page="3" href=(some url)>Page 3</a>
```

Is it possible to fill the `data-ci-pagination-page` with ID of an article like this?

```
<a data-ci-pagination-page="23" href="http://example.com/read/23">Article 23</a>
<a data-ci-pagination-page="31" href="http://example.com/read/31">Article 31</a>
<a data-ci-pagination-page="109" href="http://example.com/read/109">Article 109</a>
```

I've tried to show the post with limit 1, but I can't figure the prev/next ID, title, etc.

Excuse me for my bad spelling, but this is what I can explain. Any sharing of schema, logic, trial and error, etc. will be appreciated.

Comment: That's not really what the pagination library is for. Consider building these links yourself and not using the pagination library in this instance.

Comment: expanding - pagination is for 'groups' of results. for example if you were showing 10 articles on each page. you want to create links for single items. typically you would foreach on the results to build the links. so try something else and post again if you are stuck.